# unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator

Tags: flutter

I Created an Emulator on Windows 10 without Installing Android Studio. But when I try to launch it, I get this error. Please help me. How can I fix this..?

```
C:\Users\This pc\AppData\Local\android\emulator>emulator -avd nexus
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.2.10.0 (build_id 8420304) (CL:N/A)
WARNING | Crash service did not start

WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
WARNING | cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed
WARNING | cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed
INFO    | added library C:\Users\This pc\AppData\Local\android\emulator\lib64\vulkan\vulkan-1.dll
INFO    | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz
ERROR   | Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
Incompatible HAX module version 3,requires minimum version 4
No accelerator found.
C:\Users\This pc\AppData\Local\android\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: failed to initialize HAX: Invalid argument
```

Comment: i am running on Ubuntu. Not having the exact same problem though similar. Did you find a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this page: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.
Judging from the line in your error "Incompatible HAX module..." you need an update.

In "Windows Features" I have Hyper-V unchecked, Virtual Machine Platform and Windows Hypervisor Platform checked.
Here's similar output from my machine where I have a working emulator set to x86 and api 30. My problem is getting my app running on api 31+ and 86_64.

INFO    | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz

INFO    | added library vulkan-1.dll

ERROR   | Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2

WHPX on Windows 10.0.22000 detected.

Windows Hypervisor Platform accelerator is operational